# Can't mount an encrypted btrfs partition: wrong fs type

Tags: mount, partition, disk, btrfs, luks

#### Problem

I've a 2TB external hdd which has 2 partitions(a 1.4TB encrypted `btrfs` and a 500GB `exfat`).
And I can't mount the `btrfs` partition, the 500GB `exfat` is fine tho.

#### Context

It's cable or socket is lose so if I move it a bit it disconnects. 
I was copying some files to `btrfs` partition and in middle of transfer it stopped, I might have accidentally touched or moved the drive or the cable.

> Why would I saved my data on such drive? because I'm stupid and
> deserve to lose my data.

#### Errors

I try to mount the partition doing:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 mydata
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdc1:
```

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/mydata /home/user/test
mount: /home/user/test: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/mydata, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

```
$ dmesg
....
....
[ 5370.588850] EXT4-fs (dm-0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 5370.589194] EXT4-fs (dm-0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 5370.589569] EXT4-fs (dm-0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 5370.610095] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
[ 5370.610451] FAT-fs (dm-0): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 5370.610454] FAT-fs (dm-0): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 5370.610953] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev dm-0
[ 5370.611440] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

#### Update

I will add any asked info in this section:

```
$ mount -t btrfs
// doesn't show the external drive partitions
```

```
$ btrfs filesystem show
// doesn't output anything
```

```
$ sudo file -sL /dev/mapper/mydata
/dev/mapper/mydata: data
```

```
$ sudo hexdump -C /dev/mapper/mydata | less
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00010000  63 75 4c 3c 92 25 48 d0  ee 2a 51 52 dd 68 3e 61  |cuL<.%H..*QR.h>a|
00010010  97 11 4e ae cb 91 26 4b  76 95 4d 38 3c 78 a7 2a  |..N...&Kv.M8<x.*|
00010020  7a 20 1c ce 5b 46 bd bd  71 e3 2d 3c 72 9c d4 d5  |z ..[F..q.-<r...|
00010030  b1 79 cb d2 30 d9 6d ca  13 01 4e 43 14 c6 99 7e  |.y..0.m...NC...~|
00010040  d7 f9 47 ab b7 32 8a 4e  38 7b 73 7f a2 17 58 fc  |..G..2.N8{s...X.|
00010050  a4 66 52 c6 5a 09 b1 b8  0a db cc 46 ef e8 17 7b  |.fR.Z......F...{|
00010060  c9 c0 94 7a da 98 19 b6  1e 5e dc b5 c9 37 86 e5  |...z.....^...7..|
00010070  fb eb b4 ad 02 e5 36 72  3a b3 47 1e 0a 78 8c f8  |......6r:.G..x..|
00010080  d4 a7 83 cb be 9a dd c1  d0 f1 29 f0 47 78 5f f7  |..........).Gx_.|
00010090  31 27 85 e6 65 0d 11 55  0d 92 c5 0b ae f9 e6 67  |1'..e..U.......g|
000100a0  fd 1b ee 03 21 10 9e 73  76 1e 1c 39 ae 50 1c 41  |....!..sv..9.P.A|
000100b0  77 2f 42 e8 08 ce f9 e7  23 b6 5a 82 4e 6b 5d 03  |w/B.....#.Z.Nk].|
000100c0  01 ee 19 74 8a 31 00 25  54 c3 14 e6 eb 18 83 03  |...t.1.%T.......|
000100d0  33 a9 d1 d2 58 e9 5a f6  5c 3f 61 26 75 b0 c2 61  |3...X.Z.\?a&u..a|
000100e0  24 c5 c9 f3 dc 6b 3a f6  09 3d ce 5f 86 42 a2 d2  |$....k:..=._.B..|
000100f0  d9 d1 00 bb e0 f0 8f c1  f4 6b 93 51 1d 51 94 53  |.........k.Q.Q.S|
00010100  39 2d 43 94 da fc fb 9b  b3 e2 75 cf 88 f0 1e c4  |9-C.......u.....|
00010110  5e 2f a9 8a f1 eb 88 55  17 c9 32 6d 21 d3 82 1f  |^/.....U..2m!...|
00010120  59 4e 7a b9 18 0a 77 d4  62 19 65 54 62 af 9d bc  |YNz...w.b.eTb...|
00010130  6f 45 7c 0a 2f a3 93 69  a6 27 29 8c 6f 1d d8 57  |oE|./..i.').o..W|
00010140  2a 83 60 e7 e3 cd 05 de  79 d7 51 b5 25 47 81 c0  |*.`.....y.Q.%G..|
00010150  b9 7d ab b7 e6 85 b8 85  e2 60 58 11 5f c3 78 30  |.}.......`X._.x0|
00010160  8c 10 1d d3 f4 cd 49 38  6b 25 c9 bf 47 47 d9 e5  |......I8k%..GG..|
00010170  15 65 42 e7 a9 87 4d 7a  d5 11 64 5b cd 78 50 97  |.eB...Mz..d[.xP.|
00010180  38 eb 6c c6 5a ee 4b fe  6e 8f dc 84 88 a9 fa ea  |8.l.Z.K.n.......|
00010190  47 f6 a0 00 44 8c 65 c4  7d 54 a1 a7 25 9d cd e0  |G...D.e.}T..%...|
000101a0  d9 7a 9e 10 ed b7 ae 68  05 7a 48 7b fa ae 5c 54  |.z.....h.zH{..\T|
000101b0  49 13 98 a2 56 b4 d1 16  56 67 11 07 f9 8a 4b dc  |I...V...Vg....K.|
000101c0  68 10 37 40 92 e4 a1 f1  77 0a 91 ec 6a bd 09 f1  |h.7@....w...j...|
000101d0  15 c3 5e 49 b9 0a 98 0d  40 4c a4 83 5e 54 af 75  |..^I....@L..^T.u|
000101e0  1b 9d ab 60 65 2e 50 10  cf f6 fc 6e 29 23 b8 48  |...`e.P....n)#.H|
000101f0  d2 e8 5b 79 26 ca ab f8  94 e4 91 19 ff 4f d9 e9  |..[y&........O..|
00010200  3d 74 a3 b9 fd ec 3d 43  a7 52 d3 c4 17 36 e7 24  |=t....=C.R...6.$|
00010210  3d e9 58 c0 0a dc 44 52  51 2d 7c 72 de 76 07 53  |=.X...DRQ-|r.v.S|
00010220  12 13 d1 18 20 54 7a ed  22 77 6d 86 b8 c6 fc 74  |.... Tz."wm....t|
00010230  c8 bb 8b b4 f0 60 d2 44  f4 a0 17 c0 d4 86 18 1c  |.....`.D........|
00010240  f1 3a 08 de 0f d8 40 d7  2e 80 2e f4 4c 62 28 02  |.:....@.....Lb(.|
00010250  0c 82 a8 42 6a 55 0a 53  9e af cc a3 2f 90 6f ad  |...BjU.S..../.o.|
00010260  9a 8e ae d7 3a 57 07 b3  82 2c b9 50 dc 67 ee 4f  |....:W...,.P.g.O|
00010270  48 f3 c8 8b 8c 43 dd d4  5a 00 df 31 79 3b 26 d0  |H....C..Z..1y;&.|
00010280  b3 b5 68 dc cf c4 a7 d6  c4 8b 00 12 f7 7a 80 c6  |..h..........z..|


// This is only the first page
```

```
$ sudo strings /dev/mapper/mydata | less
cuL<
M8<x
N8{s
Aw/B
\?a&u
S9-C
I8k%
`e.P
DRQ-|r
1y;&
n~EJ
j/t}
H>*c<
Ky@A
>oO~
[hTdX
9 ko
_k.V
i/T9
7`4N(B"~
@8"'
;0cu+
uo2Eqa
-}+U
,$!2
iOV&
b\`m'
]VRH
=j`A
hMPz
=[f+
Q$W3.
`d:&
\B,0
OH}u{
SyL(/
|>7l
d}1     
-8%r-
>+yx!
){:!
hoS.
%f:;

// This is only the first page
```

```
$ sudo hexdump --skip 64M -C -n 512 /dev/mapper/mydata | less










04000000  2b 00 ee 8a d2 f3 fa ab  e9 67 fe 27 12 57 8a b8  |+........g.'.W..|
04000010  91 4f e7 2c 41 59 79 9f  f4 1b ac b0 0b 68 18 55  |.O.,AYy......h.U|
04000020  eb 62 c4 f1 41 63 95 91  f6 3d c0 4c 0b 37 02 36  |.b..Ac...=.L.7.6|
04000030  34 e0 f3 b4 5d 8b bd 1d  55 6b dc 4c c4 02 b3 2b  |4...]...Uk.L...+|
04000040  6a 2f 74 50 00 76 d1 31  8e cc 4e 64 53 14 ff 61  |j/tP.v.1..NdS..a|
04000050  bf dc 48 94 6b 12 26 1e  36 68 c3 d1 aa 83 3d 15  |..H.k.&.6h....=.|
04000060  01 51 12 bb d8 44 f2 01  59 fe 61 30 20 46 9d 3b  |.Q...D..Y.a0 F.;|
04000070  1e 3c 93 21 1c 89 26 7f  a2 cf ab e1 1a 3e 58 b2  |.<.!..&......>X.|
04000080  00 a0 dd cb dc 44 ff 69  f4 63 d8 ee 55 15 7a 6b  |.....D.i.c..U.zk|
04000090  cc 2a 15 9f 2f 0f a6 c7  e3 7d b7 40 d4 31 16 d8  |.*../....}.@.1..|
040000a0  36 79 79 7d ca c5 7c b6  7e ab bf b8 1e 6c f3 41  |6yy}..|.~....l.A|
040000b0  aa ce bb 49 5e a8 c7 5a  b3 fe 5b 73 ac ef f4 8b  |...I^..Z..[s....|
040000c0  22 01 0e 3f 22 d8 da 9f  2d 86 fd e7 81 ab 78 1e  |"..?"...-.....x.|
040000d0  dd 5c 61 c2 c2 0b 3e 0b  97 3d ae c9 c0 85 58 7f  |.\a...>..=....X.|
040000e0  71 0b 20 4e 19 52 51 69  a0 be e2 41 bc 01 a0 ad  |q. N.RQi...A....|
040000f0  cc fc 49 3f 16 2a f5 a5  ae 1d ca 22 65 75 df 56  |..I?.*....."eu.V|
04000100  b9 39 c2 20 8d 19 97 27  e5 ec c6 67 9f 53 e8 0d  |.9. ...'...g.S..|
04000110  ed ff 25 16 a1 1f 0e 23  7f 5d 3b 8a 00 a2 33 94  |..%....#.];...3.|
04000120  6b 0d 7d d8 a7 81 45 4b  73 41 00 41 da 58 e2 14  |k.}...EKsA.A.X..|
04000130  0d 0c 37 bc 91 36 32 57  9f 03 f0 f8 26 2c c0 01  |..7..62W....&,..|
04000140  2e a4 ba 5b 28 35 8f 44  b9 5f b1 be 6f 5d 37 06  |...[(5.D._..o]7.|
04000150  d6 14 38 3d 3d 79 e0 30  16 3f 38 f5 78 e7 d5 c2  |..8==y.0.?8.x...|
04000160  37 9d 44 01 65 ce f7 31  d3 71 87 6c 33 bf 54 81  |7.D.e..1.q.l3.T.|
04000170  1a c0 37 c2 8b 32 19 42  b4 7b 16 c5 d3 52 a5 8b  |..7..2.B.{...R..|
04000180  3d 1e 9e e5 e5 7e 7a b1  0d 1a fb 03 48 ae 97 05  |=....~z.....H...|
04000190  20 2b ce 99 61 85 da 30  ce a5 c6 21 b2 06 b7 f7  | +..a..0...!....|
040001a0  43 3d 18 d9 6e af df 05  5c 24 b9 be b2 fa dc 8e  |C=..n...\$......|
040001b0  e6 2f 59 6c 30 6b ee b8  de 10 6d 82 0b 1e 71 14  |./Yl0k....m...q.|
040001c0  10 ef f5 10 d7 75 09 64  3a 6b f1 47 67 9f 2d 6a  |.....u.d:k.Gg.-j|
040001d0  d1 73 d4 6c 73 bf 35 79  33 b8 30 f2 97 3b 08 6f  |.s.ls.5y3.0..;.o|
040001e0  54 0f 38 ae 2c ea 94 c1  84 7a 8f 1d d7 69 5b e8  |T.8.,....z...i[.|
040001f0  4f 95 e8 de f0 cc d0 20  49 83 b8 15 27 05 72 4a  |O...... I...'.rJ|
04000200
```

```
$ sudo hexdump -C /dev/sdc1 | less
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  78 74 73 2d 70 6c 61 69  |........xts-plai|
00000030  6e 36 34 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |n64.............|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 40  |...............@|
00000070  6b b3 a5 73 7a 87 ea e7  03 12 74 76 42 6b 2b c0  |k..sz.....tvBk+.|
00000080  1c e2 f3 60 1e d1 87 6d  54 5c 76 fe f7 87 a3 36  |...`...mT\v....6|
00000090  da 7c e7 79 ab bd ce 3a  6a 45 4a 39 73 2a 1e bf  |.|.y...:jEJ9s*..|
000000a0  f5 83 bc eb 00 01 1f f6  36 35 36 62 31 31 62 38  |........656b11b8|
000000b0  2d 64 36 38 38 2d 34 62  62 66 2d 62 36 34 63 2d  |-d688-4bbf-b64c-|
000000c0  66 64 33 63 61 62 30 32  64 36 64 31 00 00 00 00  |fd3cab02d6d1....|
000000d0  00 ac 71 f3 00 11 f5 14  90 05 11 44 d4 61 d2 57  |..q........D.a.W|
000000e0  60 f3 b1 f0 37 0e 65 57  fb c8 a2 e6 09 a3 d1 b1  |`...7.eW........|
000000f0  59 c2 66 22 79 b1 84 e3  00 00 00 08 00 00 0f a0  |Y.f"y...........|
00000100  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 02 00 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000130  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 03 f8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000160  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 05 f0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000190  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 07 e8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001c0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 09 e0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001f0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0b d8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000220  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0d d0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  42 d1 38 45 68 28 e8 ad  08 3f 2b de 72 6a 41 48  |B.8Eh(...?+.rjAH|
00001010  47 f3 3c bb 8b 95 40 5b  3d e9 c5 37 00 41 5d 3c  |G.<...@[=..7.A]<|
00001020  f4 eb 35 90 29 79 4e a8  ca ff eb 85 f7 42 ec 81  |..5.)yN......B..|
00001030  c2 6c e0 2d d0 6b 5d 95  4b 43 e7 b3 62 d1 58 74  |.l.-.k].KC..b.Xt|
```

As asked to confirm the outputs I did physically disconnected and reconnected the drive and did test with a name other than `mydata` and the result were the same.

On a not-directly related note I got curios and did one test one other partition of my pc (on another disk) which is also `btrfs` but not encrypted and here is the result:

```
$ sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda1 | less
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00010000  7a 9f 1b a6 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |z...............|
00010010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00010020  d6 b9 03 49 28 83 47 2f  90 20 ab 6f 95 c7 05 26  |...I(.G/. .o...&|
00010030  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00010040  5f 42 48 52 66 53 5f 4d  cb 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |_BHRfS_M........|
00010050  00 80 10 e7 25 00 00 00  00 40 79 01 00 00 00 00  |....%....@y.....|
00010060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00010070  00 00 b0 98 4f 00 00 00  00 60 f4 f6 27 00 00 00  |....O....`..'...|
00010080  06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00010090  00 10 00 00 00 40 00 00  00 40 00 00 00 10 00 00  |.....@...@......|
000100a0  81 00 00 00 7f 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000100b0  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 61 03 00 00  |............a...|
000100c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000100d0  00 00 00 b0 98 4f 00 00  00 00 00 80 41 29 00 00  |.....O......A)..|
000100e0  00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000100f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00010100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 71 2b f6 ab 7c  |...........q+..||
00010110  2e 45 26 a3 88 95 5b a3  25 55 b9 d6 b9 03 49 28  |.E&...[.%U....I(|
00010120  83 47 2f 90 20 ab 6f 95  c7 05 26 44 6f 77 6e 6c  |.G/. .o...&Downl|
00010130  6f 61 64 73 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |oads............|
00010140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00010230  00 00 00 cb 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00010240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00010320  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
00010330  00 00 00 e4 00 00 50 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00  |......P.........|
00010340  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00  |................|
00010350  00 00 00 00 22 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00  |...."...........|
00010360  00 00 01 00 00 10 00 00  02 00 01 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
00010370  00 00 00 00 00 00 50 01  00 00 00 00 71 2b f6 ab  |......P.....q+..|
00010380  7c 2e 45 26 a3 88 95 5b  a3 25 55 b9 01 00 00 00  ||.E&...[.%U.....|
00010390  00 00 00 00 00 00 d0 01  00 00 00 00 71 2b f6 ab  |............q+..|
000103a0  7c 2e 45 26 a3 88 95 5b  a3 25 55 b9 00 00 00 01  ||.E&...[.%U.....|
000103b0  00 00 00 00 00 22 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  |....."..........|
000103c0  00 00 00 01 00 00 10 00  00 02 00 01 00 01 00 00  |................|
000103d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50  01 00 00 00 00 71 2b f6  |.......P.....q+.|
000103e0  ab 7c 2e 45 26 a3 88 95  5b a3 25 55 b9 01 00 00  |.|.E&...[.%U....|
000103f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d0  01 00 00 00 00 71 2b f6  |.............q+.|
00010400  ab 7c 2e 45 26 a3 88 95  5b a3 25 55 b9 00 00 00  |.|.E&...[.%U....|
00010410  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|

// This is only the first page
```

Comment: Why don't you use mount.btrfs instead of mount that seems to not support BTRFS : see https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: Hey @admstg, are you sure `mount.btrfs` is a thing? I can't find anything about it. also it's not in `sbin` dir.

Comment: `mount -t btrfs` ... does `btrfs filesystem show` see any? `file -sL /dev/mapper/mydata`? is btrfs module loaded, shown in /proc/filesystems?

Comment: @frostschutz the `mount -t btrfs` only shows my internal drives and not the external which is the problem, the `btrfs filesystem show` doesn't show any output, the `file -sL /dev/mapper/mydata`  shows `/dev/mapper/mydata: data`

Comment: `sudo hexdump -C /dev/mapper/mydata | less` or `strings /dev/mapper/mydata | less` ... btrfs should show `_BHRfS_M`

Comment: @frostschutz I didn't know where to look so I added the first page of the output to my answer(update section).

Comment: Do not cross post.

Comment: something wiped the first 64K of data with zeroes. everything afterwards looks random. you could still check secondary header  `hexdump --skip 64M -C -n 512 /dev/mapper/...` but it doesn't look good so far... doesn't look like btrfs at all. not sure what to tell you, sorry.

Comment: @frostschutz Isn't the first 64 KiB [irrelevant to Btrfs](https://superuser.com/q/1208555/432690)?

Comment: @frostschutz @ KamilMaciorowski come on guys give something work with here, I really need those data, the 1s and 0s are on the disk right? I didn't  fully erase the data, could this randomness be related to luks? even the list of file/dir names could help me. also I've added secondary headers to my answer,

Comment: So far the only thing we know for sure is: this device is LUKS formatted, opened, and 64K of \0 was written to it. Everything else we've seen so far looks random, expected btrfs structures are missing. At this point you want to check raw data on both sdc1 and /dev/mapper/cryptsdc1. You want to find random data on sdc1, and sensible data on cryptsdc1. If sdc1 is all zero, you won't find anything on cryptsdc1 either.

Comment: Can you rule out a device name mixup? Maybe you opened another luks container as mydata before?

Comment: @frostschutz I redid the tests with a name other than `mydata` but the result were the same, also I've updated the answer and added more info, also I wanted to say I really appreciate you'r help and means a lot so thank you.

Comment: I only disagree with the statement that "something wiped the first 64K of data with zeroes". All my Btrfs-s have 64 KiB of zeros from the beginning. These zeros are normal for Btrfs and possibly a red herring. (Trivia: once I even managed to put a partition table within these 64 KiB, so my device worked as a superfloppy or a partitioned device equally well.) Still the later content of your device truly does not look like Btrfs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski so I've got a working `btrfs` partition which I added `hexdump` of it to my answer which has the mentioned `_BHRfS_M` and also lable of partition in its string forms and my faulty partition doesn't, but a few page down I can tell which is which, is there pattern to strings for `btrfs` to tell? also could it be a few corrupted blocks/headers at begging of partition, if so is there a way to fix it? thank you btw.

Comment: There's a hidden feature in each modern system: It's called "syslog" or "journal". *What does it say arount the times you had problems?*